# Is there any way to open command prompt and execute some command using a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have tried this code this code works fine but I want to add more code so it becomes complex to write it in one function only I want to use another it in different line. Is there any way?

I have tried saving this in some variable and accessing it but it doesn't work:

```
os.system('cmd.exe /K "cd %s & activate & mkdir  C:\Private\PY36-VirtualEnv\Source\%s &  cd C:\Private\PY36-VirtualEnv\Source\%s  & code . " '%(path_list[which_dir - 1] , new_folder,new_folder))
```

Comment: use subprocess for executing external command and catching their errors and outputs. refer [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: why dont you create a simple cmd file (if windows ) or shell script to execute you command.

Comment: Yeah but how to create a command file ? in windows i am working on

Comment: create a file with **.bat** extension.
`@echo off 
cd %1 & activate & mkdir  C:\Private\PY36-VirtualEnv\Source\%2 &  cd C:\Private\PY36-VirtualEnv\Source\%2  & code . `
Here %1 and %2 are you command line arguments. Simply run **xyz.bat arg1 arg2**

Answer (score -1):

why you use python for this work?
if you can just code it with c#. it is very powerful for cmd works.
try to use c# and then connect it to your python.
C# code is ready on internet.

Comment: I want to use python only ? is that any way in python ?